# Can't select a button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm making a Rock Paper Scissors Game to practice DOM manipulation and I have to select a button in JavaScript to know user's choice.

I created an event listener to each button but somehow when the event fires it's target is one of the button's children nodes (in my search I discovered that this is related to event bubbling I think).
I tried to use capture, but it's not working too.
So I'm trying to use a recursive function to grab the parent node until it reaches the button itself. But in the console, when it actually reaches the button node, it returns undefined and doesn't attribute to `buttonChecked`.

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.game__button')
 
buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('mousedown', rockPaperScissors, {capture:true}));

function checkValidOption(element){
    if(element.hasAttribute('data-option')){
        console.log(element.nodeName);
        return element;
    }
    else {
        console.log("Not Found it")
        element = element.parentNode;
        checkValidOption(element);
    }
}

function rockPaperScissors(event) {
    let buttonPressed = event.target;
    let buttonChecked = checkValidOption(buttonPressed);
    console.log(buttonChecked);
    // A lot of comments below

}
```

```html
    <button class="game__button" data-option="1">
          <figure class="game__figure">
                <div>
                     <img class="game__figure--img" src="images/icons8-rock-80.png" alt="">
                 </div>
                 <figcaption class="game__figure--figcaption">Rock</figcaption>
           </figure>
    </button>
```

Comment: Try `event.currentTarget` to get the component the listener was added to, rather than an internal element.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Thanks!!!!! That finally worked, but what the difference between event.target and event.currentTarget?

Comment: See [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67128309/1762224) below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `event.currentTarget` to get the component the listener was added to, rather than an internal element.

See: [Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

> *The **`currentTarget`** read-only property of the `Event` interface identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to `Event.target`, which identifies the element on which the event occurred and which may be its descendant.*

The `event.target` could be the button, or any child within the button. If we only want the button, no matter where it is clicked, reference the event's current target (the owner of the event).

```js
let buttonPressed = event.currentTarget; // Only need to change this line
```

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.game__button')

buttons.forEach(button =>
  button.addEventListener('mousedown', rockPaperScissors, { capture: true }));

function checkValidOption(element) {
  if (element.hasAttribute('data-option')) {
    console.log(element.nodeName);
    return element;
  } else {
    console.log("Not Found it")
    element = element.parentNode;
    checkValidOption(element);
  }
}

function rockPaperScissors(event) {
  let buttonPressed = event.currentTarget;
  let buttonChecked = checkValidOption(buttonPressed);
  console.log(buttonChecked);
  // A lot of comments below
}
```

```html
<button class="game__button" data-option="1">
  <figure class="game__figure">
    <div>
      <img class="game__figure--img" src="images/icons8-rock-80.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <figcaption class="game__figure--figcaption">Rock</figcaption>
 </figure>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the event up on the `button` elements and then use `this` to refer to the button that gets clicked which triggers the handler. From there, you can access anything about that object (including its nested content).

```js
// The click event is more appropriate than mousedown for buttons.
document.querySelectorAll('.game__button').forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', rockPaperScissors));

function rockPaperScissors(event) {
  // In a DOM event handler, "this" will reference the
  // DOM object that is handling the event, not necessarially
  // the object that triggered the event (which is event.target).
  console.log(this);
  console.log("You clicked: " + this.querySelector("figcaption").textContent);
}
```

```css
img { height: 50px; }
```

```html
<button class="game__button" data-option="1">
 <figure class="game__figure">
   <div>
     <img class="game__figure--img" src="https://images.thdstatic.com/productImages/94af8836-0338-4802-914e-04cc71e562ad/svn/backyard-x-scapes-fake-rocks-hdd-rof-rocsb-64_1000.jpg" alt="rock">
   </div>
   <figcaption class="game__figure--figcaption">Rock</figcaption>
 </figure>
</button>
<button class="game__button" data-option="2">
 <figure class="game__figure">
   <div>
     <img class="game__figure--img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/52/Continuous_form_paper_%2814p875_x_11%29.jpg" alt="paper">
   </div>
   <figcaption class="game__figure--figcaption">Paper</figcaption>
 </figure>
</button>
<button class="game__button" data-option="3">
 <figure class="game__figure">
   <div>
     <img class="game__figure--img" src="https://cdn.thewirecutter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/scissors-kitchen-shears-lowres.jpg" alt="scissors">
   </div>
   <figcaption class="game__figure--figcaption">Scissors</figcaption>
 </figure>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Well you just need to store the value of recursion in a variable. As simple as that.

### Like this in else block -:

```
console.log("Not Found it");
element = element.parentNode;
let buttonElement = checkValidOption(element);
return buttonElement;
```

### Full function -:

```
 function checkValidOption(element) {
    if (element.hasAttribute("data-option")) {
        console.log(element.nodeName);
        return element;
    } else {
        console.log("Not Found it");
        element = element.parentNode;
        let buttonElement = checkValidOption(element);
        return buttonElement;
    }
}
```